# Buddypress add field groups to registration page

Tags: wordpress, registration

I  have a WordPress/Buddypress installation and need the registration page to have all the field groups I set up. In other words, I set up the following field groups: Personal Info, Professional Info, Contact Info, etc with fields in them.

These groups come up when a user edits their profile, but I'm afraid they're not going to return to the profile edit to finish entering all their info up. So I would need all these field groups & fields to show up when they register.

How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

On the admin panel, when you are setting the "Extra Personal Fields" there's an option where you can set them to be "Required". All "Required" fields will appear on Registration/Sign Up form page.